# How can I programmatically create a Profile 2 profile?

Tags: 7, users

I am taking a look in the Profile 2 API documentation:
http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/profile2/function

I guess `profile_create()` or `profile2_save()` are what I need. But I have read somewhere `profile_create()` is deprecated.

Any example for how to create a Profile 2 profile programmatically?

Comment: Note that that is not an official help/docs site.

Comment: @Alfonso_MA – Where have you read that? Have you already tried the mentioned functions? Or simply looked into the module's code?

Answer (score 2):

Yes `profile_create()` is deprecated. You should use `profile2_create()` instead.

See the [*profile2.module* file](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/profile2/blob/7.x-1.6/profile2.module#L308-313):

> ```
> /**
>  * Deprecated. Use profile2_create().
>  */
> function profile_create(array $values) {
>   return new Profile($values);
> }
> ```